# How to write ember.js components work require.js

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, components

No code involved yet, so morning to show. I am trying to get into it.

I am writing an ember.js application, using require.js as AMD. I am trying to wrote an ember component, and having a hard time deciding what goes where.

The templates are in their own directory and loaded by need using text.js (in the 'define' statement of require), and compiled in the ember view.

As far as I understand, the components need to be in /components directory, which I have done. But what from there? At what route/view/controller do I load them, and how do I compile them? I tried just loading and compiling in the view, but that have me an error, complaining about env not being there. I tried extending Ember.Component and compiling there, but I he l got the same error.

Did someone ever implement components using require.js? Can you me a skeleton of how it looks like?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to go with ember-cli simply because that will be the official way to go and thus you will face less issues and more help from here when you do face problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it with require.js per se but if you download [Ember App Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/), they're using [EcmaScript 6 Modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

Still, the modules are transpiled to require.js modules by `es6-module-transpiler`, so I assume it has to be similar. Moreover, you're free to use require.js inside the files as well.

Remember that the component's name has to be in the form: `my-name`, at least one dash (`-`) included.

Out of curiosity: why don't you use [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com) or aforementioned Ember App Kit?

Comment: Regarding CLI - I am a home developer, doing small scale. I looked into ember CLI, but it requires having node.js installed, which is another layer to learn,and seems like an overkill (maybe I am wrong about this).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're level is but installing node.js is pretty easy, then you've got a server running for you for free (you don't have to configure any Apache or nginx); the only one thing you have to do is you have to install dependencies (`npm install`, maybe `bower install`) and run it (`npm start`)

Comment: i am using play-framework for backend (Scala), which already gives me the back end.
just for fun, i did install nodejs, bower and ember-cli, and creating an ember application seems to work. the big question now is how do i get them to play together - play framework and ember-cli...

Comment: oh it's really easy now! :) it's even preferred that you keep them separately! just point all your AJAX requests to your Play! API, leverage the power of Ember's adapters and serializers and bob's your uncle! :)